# Does Git not generate a merge conflict when moving/deleting a section of code that contains changes from another squash?

Tags: git

To trace back the events in chronological order:

1. User 1: started working on a feature.  He creates a branch off the
   main branch.
2. User 1: Moved a list of entries from a parent class to child
   classes, deleting a section of code, but the branch requires
   additional significant refactoring.  Squashing is delayed until the
   refactoring is complete.
3. User 2: To add a much smaller feature, User 2 added an entry to a
   list (that was deleted in User 1's branch) and squashed it into the
   main branch.
4. User 1: as part of best practices, merges the main branch into his
   dev branch (regular merge, not squashing).  Does not receive an explicit merge conflict that the
   list he moved/deleted contained an additional entry, thus breaking User 2's new feature.

So my question is correct behavior on Git's part?  That is possible to delete more code than previously intended, and not throw up a merge conflict?

Also, as additional information if it helps, we're using BitBucket Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

I recreated the merge, and it did generate a merge conflict warning on that section of code.  So ultimately the answer is user error.

To be fair to User 1, GitKraken made it tricky to see the additional entry in the merge conflict.  See if you can spot it:

[image]

Comment: To be unfair to User 1, this is yet another reason to use the command line. You get a merge conflict while merging in the Terminal, you _know_ you got a merge conflict!